# Check if Eval("VALUE") is null

Tags: c#, date, casting, dbnull

Quite new to `C#` I need to cast a value to add minutes to a date but it can be null. Here's how I do :

```
if(Eval("DUREE") != DBNull.Value)
{
    var duration = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DUREE"));
    var date = Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DATE"));
    var dateAsString = Convert.ToString(date.AddMinutes(duration));
    DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, dateAsString, "{0:HH:mm}") 
}
else
{
    " - "
}
```

Here the error I get :

> DataBinding : 'System.Data.DataRowView' doesn't comport properties called : '17/04/2014 13:30:00'.

So, does the check is false? Or the error is elsewhere?

Comment: Goooood lord... Split the expression into multiple statements and start debugging. That will help you find the problem more easily and you won't have to ask ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use code in aspx in place where you need the string with date or " - "

```
<%# Eval("DUREE") == DBNull.Value || Eval("DATE") == DBNull.Value
    ? " - "
    : Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DATE")).AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DUREE")))), "{0:HH:mm}") %>
```

Problem in your code that you in `DataBinder.Eval` pass second parameter string with date but not property name.

Comment: You've earned your day and saved mine.

Comment: 2 1/2 years later, this nailed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'Eval' method is returning you a date value in form of a string, is this what you are trying to do? :
`Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DATE")).AddMinutes(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DUREE")).Minute)`
That might be the answer to your problem for adding minutes.

However, the error that you are getting seems to indicate a different problem. The code that you have posted seems to be in code behind(?). `DataBinder.Eval` method will typically be used in aspx for web control like Repeater control. In which case you will have to pass the second parameter to `DataBinder.Eval` as name of a public Property.

You can check this out for clarity click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can do the addition of minutes while returning value of the property

Comment: Add checking here if(Eval("DUREE") != DBNull.Value && Eval("DATE") != DBNull.Value). But I'm not sure that problem with crash in cast.