# convert.isBDnull("foo") strange behavior

Tags: c#, dbnull

I've got the given code :

## file.ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = @"SELECT reu.duree_minutes as DUREE
                                            FROM z_reunions reu"
    List.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource";
    List.DataBind();
}
```

## file.ascx

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:ListView ID="List" runat="server">

    ...
    <%if (Convert.IsDBNull("DUREE"))
      { %>
         <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='NULL' ></asp:Label>
    <%} else { %>
         <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DUREE").GetType() %>'></asp:Label>
    <%} %>
```

And I've got the following output :

```
System.DBNull
System.DBNull
System.DBNull
System.DBNull
System.Int32
System.Int32
```

But I expect it to be :

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
System.Int32
System.Int32
```

Am I wrong ? Or is there a strange behavior ?

Comment: The string `"DUREE"` is never equal to `DBNull`. Do you mean `if (Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("DUREE"))`?

Comment: You are checking object of type string is DBNull, it's wrong.

Comment: @Samoth read my comment again. You never end up in the `if`, always in the `else`.

Comment: Because Eval("DUREE") return value of column "DUREE" of row for what you call Eval

Comment: @CodeCaster you edited it ;) I tested, it throw this `System.InvalidOperationException`

Comment: Can you show context of this code?

Comment: so, conclusion, you are wrong, because string "DUREE" is not of type System.DBNull it of type string. You are not able use Eval in if-statement, as @CodeCaster said, but exist another approach, I've answered below. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%# Eval("DUREE") == DBNull.Value ? <%# Eval("DUREE").GetType().ToString() %> : "NULL" %>
```

or just

```
<%# Eval("DUREE") == DBNull.Value ? "System.DBNull" : "NULL" %>
```

Instead using <%# Eval("DUREE").GetType().ToString() %> and "NULL"  you can add html

See here about using Eval in if-statement
[eval in if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462141/eval-in-if-statement)

You can use your code with 2 labels and use `Visible` property with `Eval`

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:ListView ID="List" runat="server">

    ...
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='NULL' Visible='<%# Eval("DUREE") == DBNull.Value %>'></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DUREE").GetType() %>' Visible='<%# Eval("DUREE") != DBNull.Value %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Your second solution works, but this lead me to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063861/check-is-evalvalue-is-null) issues